# Firebase Realtime Database read all existing data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

It seems that Firebase Realtime Database notifies me if a new item is added or deleted, etc. That is great, but how to get all existing items of which I was previously notified?

For example, suppose that my app is listing the items in the database. I started my app for the first time. And then "item 1" and "item 2" were created. Firebase notified me of "item 1" and "item 2", so I added them to the list of my app.

Now, my app was closed and restarted. If a new item "item 3" is created, I will be notified of that, but how can I retrieve "item 1" and "item 2" again? In short, I want to display all items, again.

I have searched for examples, but all examples I could find were getting events, not "reading all".

PS: I think you two for spending your time for explanation. I misunderstood how Firebase Realtime Database works; I thought I would get notified for new items only once across sessions. It seems that I could be notified of only new items by `addChildEventListener`, and I can access the entire items with `addValueEventListener` and its dataSnapshot.

Comment: I still think you have them confused. addValueEventListener will notify you every time the data changes and addListenerForSingleValueEvent will notify you only once , but the DataSnapshot you get in them depends on the query you attach it to.

Comment: For example if you add FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(key).orderByKey().limitToLast(1) to both of them, addValueEventListener passes you a snapshot of the last item sorted by key, every time a new element is added to the node and addListenerForSingleValueEvent will notify you of the same but only once. It doesn't necessarily mean the dataSnapshot you get is of the last added item but of the last item sorted by key which is what you mentioned in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the item that exist in a node at a moment, even if were added before you have restarted your app or after that, you need **`to attach a listener on that node`**. Everything in Firebase is about listeners. This means that you are listening for every change that is made in your database at that particular location. So in every moment you can have `dataSnapshot` of a particular node from your database. So assume we have a database that looks like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- users
          |
          --- userId1
          |     |
          |     --- //details
          |
          --- userId2
                |
                --- //details
```

If we attach a listener on `users` node, we can create a `List` which can contain all the users like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String userId = ds.getKey();
            list.add(userId);
            Log.d("TAG", userId);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", list);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
userId1
userId2
```

So using this code, you can get all the users, even if they been added before you restared the app of after. You get the data in real time.

Answer (score 1):

The result you get will depend on your query. If you write a query to retrieve all the items, you will get all the elements for a node like in the first block of the following example:

```
//Prefetch all the existing items for the node using a SingleValueEventListener
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            //Fetches all the existing items
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> snapshotIterable = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            for (DataSnapshot aSnapshotIterable : snapshotIterable) {
               aSnapshotIterable.getValue(Item.class);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

//Once you fetch all the existing items,add a listener on the last added item for realtime updates
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(key).orderByKey().limitToLast(1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Iterable<DataSnapshot> snapshotIterable = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
                Iterator<DataSnapshot> snapshotIterator = snapshotIterable.iterator();
                //Fetches the last added item
                if (snapshotIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Item value = snapshotIterator.next().getValue(Item.class);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```